# Verifying exactly the same variable in python list when passing by reference

Tags: python, pass-by-reference

Take the nested lists:
`list = [[foo, foo], [foo, foo]], [foo, foo]]`.

I pass `list` to a function, but I also separately pass by reference to the same function the second nested list as `list[1]`.

Then, within the function at random indices, I add 3 more `[foo, foo]`'s to `list`.

Would it be possible to identify which `[foo, foo]` in `list` is the one I passed to the function?

In other words, I want to get the new index of the original `[foo, foo]` I separately passed earlier in the now-modified `list`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is `is`, which tests if two variables refer to the same object.

Demonstrating in iPython shell:

```
In [1]: list = [['foo', 'foo'], ['foo', 'foo'], ['foo', 'foo']]

In [2]: sublist = list[1]

In [3]: sublist is list[1]
Out[3]: True

In [5]: list.insert(1, ['foo', 'foo'])

In [6]: list
Out[6]: [['foo', 'foo'], ['foo', 'foo'], ['foo', 'foo'], ['foo', 'foo']]

In [7]: list.insert(1, ['foo', 'foo'])

In [8]: list
Out[8]: 
[['foo', 'foo'],
 ['foo', 'foo'],
 ['foo', 'foo'],
 ['foo', 'foo'],
 ['foo', 'foo']]

In [9]: sublist is list [1]
Out[9]: False

In [10]: for count, l in enumerate(list):
   ...:     if l is sublist:
   ...:         print(count)
   ...: 
3

In [11]: sublist is list[3]
Out[11]: True
```

Answer (score 3):

Forensic has a good answer. You can also try the approach of modifying the function to include information about which index has the original element. This can be more efficient than testing items in a long list, if you're able to modify this function.

```
import random
foo = 4
items = [[foo, foo], [foo, foo, foo], [foo, foo]]

# parameter "index" is index of the item to keep track of
def add_items(items, index):
    new_index = -1

    for _ in range(2):
        insert_at = random.choice(range(len(items)))
        # shift to the right if inserting before
        new_index = index if insert_at > index else index + 1
        # modify items; insert a new item foo at index insert_at
        items.insert(insert_at, foo)
        
    return items, new_index

print(add_items(items, 1))
```

Output:

```
([4, [4, 4], 4, [4, 4, 4], [4, 4]], 1)
```

Comment: I chose to accept Forensic's answer as it's more straightforward and applies slightly better to my actual code (the list is fairly short), but +1 to this answer as a good alternative that's better in certain contexts. Many thanks to you both :)